# angular 6 scss issue with import: expected "{"

Tags: angular, sass, node-sass

After updating packages cannot compile .scss files. Compiler shows following error:

> ERROR in ./src/app/components/settings/settings.component.scss
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

```
$font-family: 'Segoe UI';
                        ^
      Expected "{".
  src\styles\_variables.scss 1:26  root stylesheet
  stdin 1:9                        root stylesheet
      in E:\Work\SoftServe\JiraCloud\src\MicrosoftTeamsIntegration.Jira\ClientApp\src\styles\_variables.scss (line 1, column 26)
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "proj",
  "version": "255.255.255",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "./node_modules/.bin/ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "node --no-deprecation ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --watch=false --progress=false",
    "lint": "tslint --fix -c ./tslint.json 'src/**/*.ts'"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "6.4.7",
    "@angular/cli": "6.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/material": "6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.7",
    "@types/applicationinsights-js": "1.0.7",
    "angular2-spinner": "1.0.10",
    "applicationinsights-js": "1.0.20",
    "ng-click-outside": "4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "6.3.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.8.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "4.4.4",
    "jasmine-core": "3.2.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.3.1",
    "karma-trx-reporter": "0.2.9",
    "prettier": "1.14.2",
    "protractor": "5.4.1",
    "puppeteer": "1.8.0",
    "ts-node": "7.0.1",
    "tslint": "5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "1.15.0",
    "tslint-plugin-prettier": "1.3.0",
    "typescript": "2.9.2"
  }
}
```

My _variables.scss file:

```
$font-family: 'Segoe UI';

$black: #000000;
$white: #FFFFFF;
```

My styles.scss. It shows that that it can't import 'variables'. But it should, via the scss convention of partial files. Also the same works with my _icons.scss file. Which only contains variables like `$ok: '\e412';`

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";

@import "common/inputs.component.scss";
@import "common/buttons.component.scss";
@import "common/checkboxes.component.scss";
@import "common/radio-buttons.component.scss";
@import "common/fields.scss";
@import "./cookie-consent.scss";
@import "./generic.scss";
@import "./angular-material.overrides.scss";
@import "./editable-field.scss";
@import "./variables";

html {
  max-height: 98%;
}

body {
  font-family: $font-family;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

My angular.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "jiratab": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/tabConfig.html",
              "src/loginResult.html",
              "src/logout.html",
              "src/login.html",
              "src/fonts.css",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/styles"
              ]
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "jiratab:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "jiratab:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "jiratab:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "jiratab-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application"
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "jiratab",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

Also I have tried to import like this

`import "./_variables.scss"; 
import "variables";
import "./variables.scss"`

But non of this works

Comment: Can you post here .scss code, maybe you are missing something.

Comment: plz provide code of `styles_variables.scss`.

Comment: try using `$font-family: "Segoe UI";`

Comment: @Gaspar same. I've tried a lot of options, but non is working. I have some suggestions that complier treats this files as .css, but styleext in my angular.json have option scss

Comment: Try to inspect the scss's file imported before `_variables.scss`. 
The `editable-field.scss` file may have errors and the displayed line may not be the correct.

Comment: Checked. No problems with editable-field.scss.
Building error points to variables.scss's $font-family property with `expected "{"` message

Answer (score 0):

There was an error due to global npm packages
I've done the following:

delete npm folder content from %appdata%
install @angular/cli
and make npm i in my project

From that everything build fine
Still donno where was the problem itself but this helped me